# when trying to .click() on element i get Error: Permission denied to access property 'length'

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

in my FF extension i use the addon sdk. The content script i have written works just fine.

I can find the proper div element and get the .html() output with jQuery out of it

The problem is when i try to run .click() on it i get this error:

Error: Permission denied to access property 'length'

i am running FF 32.0.3 and sdk 1.16

this the line of code that breaks:`$("#sampleid").click();`

and this is the error that i get:`System JS : ERROR resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///c:/users/andriy/appdata/local/temp/tmpthua0e.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-LetHopSfdqAf7A@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://jid1-lethopsfdqaf7a-at-jetpack/my_addon/data/scripts/jquery.js:3 - Error: Permission denied to access property 'length'`

Edit: this is my page mod:`pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentStyleFile: [self.data.url("css/style.css"), self.data.url("css/dropdown.css")],
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("scripts/jquery.js"), self.data.url("scripts/dropdown.js"), self.data.url("scripts/pageParser.js")],
    contentScriptWhen: "end",
    onAttach: function(worker){}
});`

and `pageParser.js` contains the .click() code

that was all i wrote because this was just a test extension to understand why it wont work

Edit2: this is literally all i have in pageParser.js

```
function click1(){

console.log("123456789");

//alert($('#sampleid').html());
$('#sampleid').click();

}

click1();
```

Edit 3: Im not sure but i think this might have something to do with this. Unfortunately i cant seem to modify the examples to help me

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/

Edit 4: It seems this gentleman had the same issue as me:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/greasemonkey-users/SXfpyvcQofQ

i also stopped using jQuery and now it works

Edit 5: `$("div:contains('my sample text')").click();`

Comment: Please show your code, not just the error. Could be any number of problems causing this.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i edited my question, i hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Andriy that edit is probably useless. We need to see the click handler...

Comment: Please show the contents of `pageParser.js`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie please see edit 2 (the alert shows the correct data, so i know the element exists).

Comment: Where is your `pageParser.js` file included on your page? Header? End of body?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the file gets included with the pageMod so im not sure. I pass it the contentScriptWhen: end so it will load after the page is done loading.

Comment: I suspect its something to do with the loop. Post the loop you are doing

Comment: @Noitidart please see Edit 5. not sure what loop you are referring to. After i substitute jQuery with just regular JS everything works fine.

Comment: @Noitidart it would still be great to know what is wrong so i wouldn't run into this problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it worked after ditching jquery. I think the scope you are using from had some issues with jquery. Like jquery may have been trying to access window propety which is availble in non-privelaged code but not in privelaged code. From priveleaged code all windows are available so you have to specify which one.

Comment: @Noitidart Well i guess that would make sense. it is a bit weird that it would break on FF32 but be ok on older versions. maybe the update changed a few permission settings be default.

Comment: Oh if it worked it previous version then definitely thats not the issue. :(

Comment: @Noitidart well then im out of ideas, but check out edit 3, the blog post does mention that they chaged a few things with the updates